# Algoritma DDA (Digital Diferential Analyzer)

Tags: javascript

I have a program in JavaScript, but I can't display the graph points like (2,1), (3,2), (4,2), (5,3), (6,4), (7,4), (8,5).

```js
function dda(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  var dx = x2 - x1;
  var dy = y2 - y1;


  if (Math.abs(dx) > Math.abs(dy)) {
    var step = Math.abs(dx);
  } else {
    var step = Math.abs(dy);
  }
  var x_inc = dx / step;
  var y_inc = dy / step;



  var x = x1;
  var y = y1;
  for (var k = 1; k < step; k++) {
    x = x + x_inc;
    y = y + y_inc; //I'm confused about this part

  }
  return x;

}
console.log(dda(2, 1, 8, 5));
```

Comment: what is a DDA ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to collect `x` and `y` values.

Beside this, you need to start with `k = 0` and increment the values after using the values.

```js
function dda(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    const
        dx = x2 - x1,
        dy = y2 - y1,
        step = Math.abs(dx) > Math.abs(dy)
            ? Math.abs(dx)
            : Math.abs(dy),
        x_inc = dx / step,
        y_inc = dy / step,
        result = [];

    for (let k = 0, x = x1, y = y1; k < step; k++) {
        result.push([x, y]);
        x += x_inc;
        y += y_inc;
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(dda(2, 1, 8, 5));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```